# Strange error with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I'm trying to print this image

[image]

with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0) node [pos=1,below] {$\Re$};
    \draw [->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2.5) node [pos=1,right] {$\Im$};

    \begin{scope}[thick, decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}}, mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}}}
        ] 
        \draw[orange,postaction={decorate}] (2cm,0) arc (0:180:2cm) node[pos=0,below]{$\Gamma$} node[pos=0.1,right]{$C_R^+$};
        \draw[orange,postaction={decorate}] (0.5cm,0) arc (180:0:0.5cm) node[pos=0.3,above]{$C_\varepsilon^-$};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[thick, decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}}}
        ] 
        \draw[orange,postaction={decorate}] (-2,0) -- (0.5,0);
        \draw[orange,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[fill,red] (1,0) circle (0.5mm) node[below]{$\omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which worked just fine until yesterday. Today when I tried to compile the file (through Overleaf) it gave me this error message:

> Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "output-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'output-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'output-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

I don't really understand what this means and I've had no success looking online.

Comment: You probably have other errors before this one. Please complete your code is that it can be compiled, and all the relevant packages. For example, you clearly use some kind of externalization here...